# Одинаковое имя-отчество или имена-отчества?

Tags: грамотная-речь, единственное-множественное-число

*Контекст:*

В 1983 году, ещё в советское время, Сан Саныч Завьялов завоевал Большой хрустальный глобус Кубка мира по лыжным гонкам. Спустя 37 лет другой Сан Саныч, на этот раз Большунов, повторил его успех и стал первым российским лыжником, выигравшим Кубок!

В связи с этим вопрос. Как правильно сказать: *У них одинаков**ое** им**я**-отчеств**о*** или *У них одинаков**ые** имен**а**-отчеств**а***?

Я сказал в единственном числе, потом повторил во множественном, но тогда возникло ощущение, что так неправильно, потому что хоть люди разные, да имя-отчество-то одно.

Comment: Они полные тёзки, — и без вопросов, и намного короче.

Comment: @shampar: фамилии же разные. Значит, не полные?

Comment: тезка — ТЁЗКА -и; мн. род. -зок, дат. -зкам; м. и ж. Разг. Человек, носящий одинаковое с кем-л. имя. Мы с ней тёзки. Он мой полный т. (о том, кто носит одинаковые имя и отчество с кем-л.). Толковый словарь Кузнецова
Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/ushakov/%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: @shampar: а как тогда назвать полных тёзок да ещё и с одинаковой фамилией?

Comment: На otvet.mail.ru есть такая форма: абсолютные тёзки.

Comment: Полные тёзски и в придачу однофамильцы. Хотя это всё равно не ответ на вопрос, да и  сам бы так никогда не сказал. Если кто-то скажет, что полные, то я так и пойму, что и с фамилией тоже.

Comment: Артём, поздравляю с 10k!

Comment: Спасибо большое, Александр! И главное, ровно получилось!))

Comment: Это я (извините за нескромность) добавил десятку за этот вопрос и увидел, как 9990 превратилось в 10k. :)

Comment: Я так и предположил, спасибо большое! ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> У них одинаковые имена-отчества.

Этот вариант совершенно не звучит и, более того, на мой слух, неграмматичен.

Здесь нужно использовать единственное число, которое вполне естественным образом примет [дистрибутивное значение](https://texts.news/literaturovedenie_1041/upotreblenie-edinstvennogo-chisla-znachenii-52361.html):

> У них одинаковое имя-отчество. (=У каждого своё.)

Слово, кстати, литературное, [фиксируется](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/73906) словарями, но уместней оно в разговорной речи.

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, почему вы считаете такую форму "неграмматичной". Почему "одинаковые имена" и "одинаковые фамилии" грамматичны, а эта форма - нет?

Comment: Спасибо большое, Aer, очень нравится ответ!

Comment: @ИгорьД потому что именно таков результат интроспекции. Потому что _имена и фамилии_ словосочетание, а _имена-отчества_ скорее одно слово, то есть и воспринимаются они по-разному.

Answer (score 0):

По правилам литературного языка нужно сказать так:

> У них одинаковые имена и отчества.

Если вы решили образовать несловарное слово "имя-отчество", что допустимо в разговорной речи, то логично согласовывать их так, как согласуется любое из этих слов. Преимущественно согласуют во множественном числе, но есть случаи и с единственным.

> И мать и дочь носили одинаковые имена (Ю. Тынянов)
>
> Два чиновника с одинаковым именем в этом доме (М. Лермонтов)

Comment: Имя-то ведь одно! Можно подумать, что они сменяли имена одно за другим.

Comment: Имя - понятие невещественное, поэтому нельзя однозначно сказать, было ли это одно имя или же они носили два отдельных, но совпадающих имени. Сравните: их мнения совпадали = они имели одинаковое мнение; у этих футболистов [из разных команд] одинаковые номера = у этих футболистов одинаковый номер.

Comment: Не понимаю первой фразы.

Comment: Как же слово оказалось несловарным?! https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/73906